# Merging Two menus in the backend into one menu

Tags: plugins, menus, dashboard

I'm wanting to merge two menus (actually 6 menus) that are used throughout the site into one large menu. I don't want to do this with PHP as I want the menu to be displayed using Elementor.

So far I have not found any way to do this without manually re-created a larger menu. These menus for my client are... pretty big.

I've tried using a menu plugin, none as far as I know allows this. I tried using a shortcode in menus plugin but it did not render properly.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="menu-wrapper">
   <div class="menu1">
     <?php
            wp_nav_menu( array(
                'theme_location'  => 'menu-1',
                'menu_id'         => 'top-menu',
            ) );
        ?>
   </div>
   <div class="menu2">
     <?php
            wp_nav_menu( array(
                'theme_location'  => 'menu-2',
                'menu_id'         => 'main-menu',
            ) );
        ?>
   </div>
</div>
```